# Using javascript regex to fix the following

Tags: javascript, regex

How do I turn this text:

> • Ban Ki-moon calls for immediate ceasefire• Residents targeted in
>   al-Qusayr, witnesses tell HRWIsrael ignoring expanding violence by
>   settlers, EU reports9.18am: Footage from activists suggests that
>   opposition forces continue to resist government troops.This footage...

into this text:

> Ban Ki-moon calls for immediate ceasefire. Residents targeted in
>   al-Qusayr, witnesses tell HRW. Israel ignoring expanding violence by
>   settlers, EU reports. 9.18am: Footage from activists suggests that
>   opposition forces continue to resist government troops. This
>   footage...

This needs to be fixed with javascript (multiple .replace commands are possible)

1. "• " has to be removed and replaced by a ". ", however the first "• " should just be removed
2. If there is no space after a dot ".", a space must be added (.This footage)
3. If there is no space before a time (9.18am), a space must be added
4. If there is no space before a capital letter (HRWIsrael) that is
   followed by non-capital letters, then a dot and space ". " must be added in front
   of that non-capital letter.

Comment: have you downvoted me? I am not a regex pro so I'm a bit clueless when it comes to these things. maybe you can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Breaking down into several `replace` statements (as listed below) is the way I would go about it ([working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zH3ze/)).

The `fixBullets` function will turn all bullets into HTML Entities and the `fixBulletEntities` fixes those. I did this to normalize bullets as I'm not sure if they are just bullet characters or HTML entities in your source string.

The `fixTimes` function changes "9.18am:" into " 9:18am. " (otherwise, the `fixPeriods` function makes it look like " 9. 18am" which I am sure you do not want.

One major caveat regarding the `fixCapitalsEndSentence` function... This will also convert strings like "WOrDS" into "WO. rDS" which may not be what you want.

At the least, this should get you started...

```
function fixBullets(text) {
    var bullets = /•/g;
    return text.replace(bullets, '&bullet;');
}

function fixBulletEntities(text) {
    var bulletEntities = /&bullet;/ig;
    text = text.replace(bulletEntities, '. ');
    if (text.indexOf('. ') === 0) {
        text = text.substring(2);
    }
    return text;
}

function fixTimes(text) {
    var times = /(\d+)[\.:](\d+[ap]m):?/ig;
    return text.replace(times, ' $1:$2. ');
}

function fixPeriods(text) {
    var periods = /[.](\w+)/g;
    return text.replace(periods, '. $1');
}

function fixCapitalsEndSentence(text) {
    var capitalsEndSentence = /([A-Z]{2,})([a-z]+)/g;
    text = text.replace(capitalsEndSentence, function(match1, match2, match3) {
        var len = match2.length - 1;
        var newText = match2.substring(0, len) + '. ' + match2.substring(len, len + 1) + match2.substring(len + 1) + match3;
        return newText;
    });
    return text;
}

function fixMultipleSpaces(text) {
    var multipleSpaces = /\s+/g;
    return text.replace(multipleSpaces, ' ');
}

function fixAll(text) {
    text = fixBullets(text);
    text = fixBulletEntities(text);
    text = fixTimes(text);
    text = fixPeriods(text);
    text = fixCapitalsEndSentence(text);
    text = fixMultipleSpaces(text);
    return text;
}
```